# How to implement Java Strategy pattern?

Tags: java, spring, oop, polymorphism

I have an Event interface, for every Event class implemented, I have a handler. I'm parsing some string and return Event. How can I determine what handler should be invoked using Spring. The main goal to not use if statements, just make it polymorphic. Do you have some examples?

Comment: [Strategy pattern Java example (`en.wikipedia.org`)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern#Java)

Comment: Are you sure you want a strategy pattern? The strategy is normally set explicitly. A "generic" selection from multiple handlers sounds more like a [chain of responsibility (`en.wikipedia.org`)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern).

Answer (score 0):

The Strategy Pattern consists of the following components:

- An interface common to all specific classes. This is your Event interface.
- N concrete classes that implement the interface
- A class that maintains a reference to an object whose type is that of your interface and is initialized with an instance of one of the concrete classes.

Therefore, if Strategy is really the pattern you need or want:

```
public interface Event {
    Event handle(String value);
}

public class Event1 implements Event {
    Event1 handle(String value) {
      //do whatever
    }
}

public class Event2 implements Event {
    Event2 handle(String value) {
      //do whatever
    }
}

//etc...

public class StrategyClient {
    private Event event;
    private String value;
    public StrategyClient(Event event){
        this.event=event;
    }
    public Event handle(){
        event.handle(value);
    }
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

And so you just need to initialize your `StrategyClient` with an instance of `Event1`, or `Event2`, or any of the classes that implement `Event`.